# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Missing end of comment tag

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to create a html file from my html-template with help of python and `jinja2` lib

My file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4_Xso7eyR9thXdqnntNncd07jrRNHHY/view?usp=sharing
My code:

```
import jinja2  # create html files

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
    searchpath="./"
)
data_to_render = {
    "document_number": "123",
    "building_object_address": "Moscow"
}
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
template = templateEnv.get_template("income_contract_web.html")
sourceHtml = template.render(json_data=data_to_render) 

with open("xyz_result.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(sourceHtml)
```

I have this error:

```
 File "/home/alex/root_folder/projects/61_documents/1_documents_template/jinja_html/src.py", line 14, in <module>
    template = templateEnv.get_template("income_contract_web.html")
    .......

    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "<unknown>", line 13, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Missing end of comment tag
```

I think that error deals with this line:

```
*/#sidebar{position:absolute;top
```

Are there settings in jinja to process this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is the inlined, minimized CSS that targets an id, like: `{#sidebar{` or `{#sidebar.opened+#page-container{`. By default Jinja2 uses `{#` for comments, so it tries to find the closing tag `#}`. However you can choose a [different string for these tags](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/?highlight=comment#high-level-api), e.g.:

```
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=templateLoader,
  comment_start_string='{=',
  comment_end_string='=}',
)
```

Alternatively, you can put these CSS into an external file.

Comment: I added this line, but I have error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '<'

  File "income_contract_web.html", line 1383, in template

Comment: Full line 
https://ctxt.io/2/AADgceJTEw

Comment: That's a second problem because your have things like this: `{{<span class="_ _1"></span>`. Replace every `{{` which is not Jinja2 var insert with HTML encoded version: `&#123;&#123;` same for closing braces (`}}`): `&#125;&#125;`.